# How to set subnets in /etc/mail/relay-domains?

Tags: email, sendmail

If I need to set a /27 in the mentioned config file (sendmail), how can I do it? I need to write all the 30 IP's in it? Or does it accepts /27?

Comment: If this is a new setup, consider using something more modern than sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write all the IP (or hostnames).